# Inherit Scala trait with fields in Java

Tags: java, scala, inheritance, interop, traits

I have the following Scala trait that I would like to inherit:

```
trait StreamTableSink[T] extends TableSink[T] {

  /** Emits the DataStream. */
  def emitDataStream(dataStream: DataStream[T]): Unit
}
```

that extends:

```
trait TableSink[T] {

  private var fieldNames: Option[Array[String]] = None
  private var fieldTypes: Option[Array[TypeInformation[_]]] = None
  ...
}
```

But when I inherit it in Java like this:

```
public abstract class KafkaTableSink implements StreamTableSink<Row> {
  ...
}
```

I receive the following error:

`Error:(29, 8) java: kafka.KafkaAvroTableSink09 is not abstract and does not override abstract method TableSink$$fieldTypes_$eq(scala.Option<typeinfo.TypeInformation<?>[]>) in sinks.TableSink`

where `KafkaAvroTableSink09` inherits `KafkaTableSink`

Comment: You could just make `fieldNames` and `fieldTypes` vals' instead of vars'.

Comment: That question is talking about `def`s, not `var`s, but the problem and the solution are the same.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I don't think that is the duplicate of the question that you mentioned. I don't have any issues with the "def" and I successfully implemented the abstract method. I have an issue with the fieldTypes_$eq method which seems related to "fieldTypes" var to me.

Comment: `var`s create two non-abstract methods, so you have a trait with non-abstract methods, exactly as in the linked question. Same will happen with non-abstract `val`s.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Does it mean that it's impossible to inherit traits with "var"s?

Comment: Again, the answer is the same: they can't be inherited directly, you need to write an abstract class extending the trait in Scala and inherit that class in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems might be arising.

1) java does not know what type to give fieldTypes due to the use of a placeholder type (underscore). This might lead to the generated fieldTypes_$eq method being made abstract (see [here](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/interop-between-java-and-scala) to see what java code is generated for a var)

2) scala traits cannot be extended in Java if they have any implementation details.

1 should be fixed by giving it an explicit type and 2 can be fixed by wrapping the trait in a class to extend in Java. (although 2 doesn't seem to be your problem, just something to be aware of)

Comment: No, the problem is 2. `_` in Scala is correctly translated into Java's `?` wildcard, which you can see in the error message.